# How to use proxy with vite (vue frontend) and django rest framework

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vite

So, you know when you access a view with django rest api on the browser, you get an html page, and when you send something like an ajax request, you get the json? I'm trying to figure out how to mess with the proxy setting for vite, but I can't find a single decent documentation around it. I want to redirect '/' to 'http://localhost:8000/api', but there's really weird behavior going on.
If I have a route on localhost:8000/api, I can do:

```js
//vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    server: {
        proxy: {
            //Focus here
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => { console.log(path); return path.replace('/^\/api/', '') }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```js
//todo-component.vue
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            todos: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        TodoElement
    },
    beforeCreate() {
                       //Focus here as well 
        this.axios.get('/api').then((response) => {
            this.todos = response.data
        })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(e)
            })
    }

}
```

This will return the json response as expected. However, if I try to make it so that '/' routes to 'localhost:8000/api/', like this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    server: {
        proxy: {
            //change here
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => { console.log(path); return path.replace('/^\/api/', '') }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```js
import TodoElement from "./todo-element.vue"
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            todos: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        TodoElement
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        //change here
        this.axios.get('/').then((response) => {
            this.todos = response.data
        })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(e)
            })
    }

}
```

It just spews out the html version of the api view, but with no styling, with a bunch of errors

[image]

No idea what to do. If someone could explain how this proxy works, i'd really love it. I don't want to keep writing "api/", and it'd be really valuable if I can manage to understand how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a bit confusing things and I will try to show you why.

If you redirect root path `/` to `/api`, **every request** sent to your app running at `http://localhost:3000` will be **forwarded** to `http://localhost:8000/api`. It mean that you will not be able to serve anything from the running app, but you will get an answer from the configured endpoint (`localhost:8000/api`) for every request.

To understand easily what is going on, keep in mind that this `vite config option (server.proxy)` act like a reverse proxy. As example, I take the `favicon.ico` resource of your app.

With your current configuration, when from your browser you try to access your app, the `/favicon.ico` *(and all other resources)* is then loaded from `http://localhost:8000/api/favicon.ico` and not anymore from your app running at `http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico`.

This explain all the errors in the console. Again, for example, `/static/rest_framework` is loaded from `http://localhost:8000/api/` and not `http://localhost:3000/`.

The documentation is quite clear, it's just a matter of understanding what a **http-proxy** is. To get more information you can head to https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#core-concept

Comment: Thanks, I understand and i'll give it a look :)